# Converted constant expression wording

Tags: c++, language-lawyer

[[expr.const] p9](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.const#9) defines a *converted constant expression* as:

> A *converted constant expression* of type `T` is an expression, implicitly converted to type `T`, where the converted expression is a constant expression and the implicit conversion sequence contains only [...]

In the following example:

```cpp
const int a = 42;
int b[a];
```

The standard does not specify if the conversions applied to `a` are part of the evaluation of the expression (in-fact, they are considered to be part of the full-expression, which is the init-declarator), and without specifying this, it effectively means that any glvalue expression of type `int` is a converted constant expression, since the conversions are not part of the evaluation of the resulting prvalue (the conversions are applied, resulting in a prvalue, which is then evaluated). Am I wrong, or is this a wording defect?

Comment: It says “the converted expression is a constant expression”

Comment: My English grammar tells me that *where the converted expression* applies to *A converted constant expression*

Comment: @L.F. Yes, it does, but that does not specify whether that includes the conversions that were performed (the intent is that it does)

Comment: @KrystianS It is the converted expression, so the conversions are certainly taken into consideration.

Comment: Also, does this help? http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.array#1

Comment: @L.F. Well of course the intent is to do so, however the converted expression is a prvalue of type `std::size_t`, and evaluating that prvalue does not cause any conversions to take place.

Comment: @NathanOliver I understand the intent of the wording, but I don't think the wording reflects the intent.

Comment: @KrystianS isn’t the lvalue to rvalue conversion performed?

Comment: @KrystianS This might be better suited on [English.SE](https://english.stackexchange.com/help).

Comment: So you're saying that the evaluation of the array bound doesn't include the conversions?

Comment: @L.F. Yes, but it's done as part of those conversions to get the "converted expression". Why is this a problem? Take a look at this: `int a = 0; int b[a];` obviously this is ill-formed, however, following the rules specified by the definition, the converted expression (a prvalue of type `std::size_t) must be a constant expression. The requirements for a prvalue constant expression is that it is a core constant expression, which when evaluated, must not evaluate any of the things specified in the list below it's definition, and evaluating that prvalue would cause none of the specified evaluatio

Comment: @Rakete1111 According to the definition, the "converted expression" (which one can assume you get after any conversions are done) must be a constant expression, and only the result after the conversions are done needs to be a constant expression.

Comment: @KrystianS "*evaluating that prvalue would cause none of the specified evaluatio*" what about this one: http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.const#4.8 There is still an l-to-r conversion

Comment: @KrystianS It violates the rules because it applies LTR conversion on the variable `a` which isn’t usable in constant expressions.

Answer (score 5):

I think you are being a bit too skeptical here.  In my opinion, the “converted expression” unambiguously means the “expression, with the necessary conversions performed.”  If you were to interpret as the “expression to be converted,” the past participle “converted” doesn’t feel right.  (An alternative might be the “to-be-converted expression.”)  So no, I don’t think this is a wording defect.

In this case, the lvalue `a` is converted to a prvalue of type `int` via the lvalue-to-rvalue conversion, and then converted to a prvalue of type `std::size_t` via integral conversions.  These are allowed in a constant expression, so the code is fine.

Comment: Look at my comment under the question, in a case like `int a = 0; int b[a];` after conversions it is a prvalue, which when evaluated according to the definition of a core-constant expression, meets the requirements.

Comment: @KrystianS The converted expression includes the expression prior to conversions ...  Seems you are trying to tear the “expression before conversions” and the “conversions” apart; don’t.  They are examined as a whole.

Comment: @KrystianS There is an LTR conversion on `a` which would not be a core CE. The "evaluates" applies recursively if that makes sense.

Comment: Ah, so converted expression should be interpreted as something like `static_cast<std::size_t>(+a)` rather than some arbitrary prvalue.

Comment: @KrystianS Yeah.  Also, integral promotion is not applied here and the unary plus operator can be omitted

Comment: The way I was interpreting it was that the conversion was done, and then the result, some arbitrary prvalue, is examined to see if it's a constant expression.

Comment: @KrystianS The "arbitrary" (whatever you mean by that) prvalue is the one being examined though

Comment: @Rakete1111 If it was arbitrary then it would be completely seperated from the conversions.

Comment: @KrystianS As a matter of fact, a prvalue is an expression, not merely a value. (Oops)

Comment: @KrystianS Oooh now I understand. Well that prvalue has to come from somewhere :)

Comment: So basically, to sum this up, the evaluation of an expression includes implicit conversions that are applied to it (if someone could provide a link to where this is written, if at all, it would be much appreciated)

Comment: @KrystianS You are over-generalizing this ...  I’d guess probably yes, but I can’t say for sure as a general statement.

Comment: I have: I suppose that conversions would count as side-effects, but I'm not positive.

Comment: @KrystianS No, they are definitely classified as value computation, not side effect.  They do not modify objects, do not touch volatile or I/O, and they do not call functions that do these things.

Comment: Ah, yes you are right. Otherwise, that is the sentence that specifies it.